# Start Java jar as Windows Service using SC.EXE

Tags: java

I want to start a Minecraft Server as a Service in a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine.

This command line works fine:

```
c:\Windows\System32\java.exe -cp c:\Data\minecraft-server\minecraft-server.jar com.mojang.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer -Xms512M -X mx512M
```

The I created a service using the following SC command:

```
sc config MinecraftServer binPath= "c:\Windows\System32\java.exe -cp c:\Data\minecraft-server\minecraft-server.jar com.mojang.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer -Xms512M -Xmx512M"
```

The service is created and when I start the service Windows starts it but then it comes back with a message that says:

> The service is not responding to the
>   control function.

The service does start but for some reason the command does not let the system know that it is started.

There is something simple that I've missed but I am not very experienced with Java so if anoyone here can give my guidance it would be very welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't just run any old EXE as a service. Services need to respond to callbacks from the Service Control Manager, and running a non-service EXE as a service will cause the messages you're seeing.

You can use a tool like [NSSM](https://iain.cx/src/nssm/), SRVANY, or any of a number of other service "wrapper" programs to get a non-service EXE to run as a service.

On the Java-specific front the [WinRun4J](http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/) application acts as a replacement for "java.exe" and can be used to start Java programs as services. I've used it when the command-line for a Java program was too long for the Service Control Manager to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app) on stackoverflow